# The assumption to guarantee that the second-order derivative y''= 0 at the inflection point.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In the book "Thomas' Calculus" the author wrote:

> Generally, if the second derivative exists at a point of inflection $(c, f (c))$, then $f''(c) = 0$. This follows immediately from the Intermediate Value Theorem whenever $f''$ is continuous over an interval containing $x = c$ because the second derivative changes sign moving across this interval. Even if the continuity assumption is dropped, it is still true that $f''(c) = 0$, provided the second derivative exists.

I can't really understand the last sentence: From which function the continuity assumption is dropped?

Suppose he means to drop the continuity assumption from the second-order derivative $y''$. However, he also added "second derivative exists", so it can't be the second-order $y''$ because derivative implies continuity.

And I also think he doesn't mean to drop from the first-order derivative $y'$ because he defines the inflection point this way:

> Def: A point (c, f (c)) where the graph of a function has a tangent line and where the concavity changes is a point of inflection.

The tangent line assures that the function has a derivative at the point (c, f(c)) and so it's continuous.

And it can't be the case where he means to drop the assumption from function $y=f(x)$ itself because the function has first-order derivative at the point of interest (by def.).

Comment: Existence of derivative of $f$ implies continuity of $f\,.$ Now re-think everything from sctratch. There is only one candidate from which the author can possibly drop the continuity assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the Author is conveying :

> ... This follows immediately from the Intermediate Value Theorem IF WE ASSUME f′′ is **continuous** over an interval ...
> ... Even IF WE DROP the **continuity** assumption , it is still true that f′′(c)=0, provided the second derivative ...

Basically , the Author is conveying that :

(1) we can not know whether f′′ is continuous or not ,
(2) no matter what , we will still have f′′(c)=0 when it exists.

Comment: But if the second derivative exists then it must be continuous right?

Comment: [A] No , $2^{nd}$ Derivative may or may not be continuous ! [B] When $2^{nd}$ Derivative Exists & it is Continuous , then $3^{rd}$ Derivative will Exist. [C] When $2^{nd}$ Derivative Exists & it is not Continuous , then $3^{rd}$ Derivative will not Exist.

Comment: I see it now, thank you!